# Keycloak's Required User Actions - Update Profile

Tags: keycloak

I'm using **Keycloak** for user management, and I want to add a couple of custom user attributes (company and position) to the **Update Profile** page (also known in the themes as `login-update-profile.ftl`).

I've tried to do something similar to what's described in Keycloak's docs "Custom User Attributes" section (linked [here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_custom_user_attributes)) but I always get an internal server error.

This is the piece of code I'm adding to my template. Note that it works on the `register.tfl` but not on the `login-update-profile.tfl`:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <div class="${properties.kcLabelWrapperClass!}">
       <label for="user.attributes.mobile" class="${properties.kcLabelClass!}">Mobile number</label>
   </div>

   <div class="${properties.kcInputWrapperClass!}">
       <input type="text" class="${properties.kcInputClass!}" id="user.attributes.mobile" name="user.attributes.mobile" value="${(register.formData['user.attributes.mobile']!'')}"/>
   </div>
</div>
```

Any idea on how I could move on? Thanks

Comment: when you say it doesn't work, do you mean your code is just ignored ? I mean, are there symptoms or logs you could show us ?

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
        <div class="${properties.kcFormGroupClass!} ${messagesPerField.printIfExists('user.attributes.company',properties.kcFormGroupErrorClass!)}">
            <div class="${properties.kcLabelWrapperClass!}">
                <label for="user.attributes.company" class="control-label">${msg("company")}</label>
            </div>
            <div class="${properties.kcInputWrapperClass!}">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user.attributes.company" name="user.attributes.company" value="${(user.attributes.company!'')}" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

I found the solution to this here https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-1361

Comment: do you know how to validate `company` and shows error when it's blank or does not meet certain condition (for example the length of the string)?